# Unable to switch Command Line Tools version from MacOSX13 to MacOSX12

Tags: xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

I installed the command line tools 14.1_beta_3 (SDK MacOSX13.0.sdk) and I cannot switch back to use the command line tools for an SDK that is compatible with software I am trying to build.

I have both XCode 13.4.1 `/Applications/xcode.app` AND XCode 14.1 Beta `/Applications/xcode-beta.app` installed.  XCode 13.4.1 points to Command Line Tools (Xcode 13.4.1) but I still get an error in my build that points to the beta MacOSX13 sdk.

I have tried switching the tools `xcode-select -s /Applications/XCode.app` with the same results.

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:188:1: note: 'sprintf' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
__deprecated_msg("This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead.")
```

I tried just removing the CommandLineTools folder from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools and re-installing the command line tools with only 13.4.1 but then the build says it cant find the MacOSX13.0.sdk.

NOTE: This is how to uninstall MacOSX13.0.sdk or switch to MacOSX12.sdk, not how to make it compile with the MacOSX13 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was caused by either the ccache needed to be cleared or the ccache itself was outdated. I updated the ccache via macports (which cleared the cache) and the references to the MacOSX13 went away when I rolled back the Command Line Tools.